# dynamic cursors when using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb6

There are keyset cursors and dynamic cursors available when using VB6 (through ADO). Therefore if another user performs an insert or delete whilst you are looping through a recordset then this change is reflected in the recordset.

VB.NET, with ADO.net, has datareaders (forward only cursor), datatables, data sets and dataadapters. How do you implement a dynamic cursor using .net.

i have spent some time reading through the class references on msdn but i have not found an answer.

Comment: ADO.NET has nothing like dynamic cursors.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get is using the [DataTable.Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.merge(v=vs.110).aspx) method. This will take 2 DataTables and merge them into 1 new DataTable with the records you want in both. The link will give you more info on how it does this and what your options are with changed record.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a pattern for looking for new records whilst looping through a data reader or datatable?

Comment: The Datatable.Merge will/can merge data from 2 DataTable where the Primary Key(s) match and the RowState is Unchanged. You also can decide what to do when the rowstate is changed. There is no looping involved. IE, `DT1.Merge(dt2)`